# React Antd dynamic dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using Antd dropdown menu component with a JSON, I want to create a dynamic menu that changes depending on my JSON (that I am fetching using express)

so far I have

```
    const menu = (
  <Menu onClick={onClick}>
    {
    this.state.getSoftware.map((data,i) => (<Menu.item key={i}>{data.Name}</Menu.item>))
    }
  </Menu>
);
```

but this does not seem to be working, any help would be great!

Comment: It's `Menu.Item` not `Menu.item`

Comment: You'll want to make sure you're passing `{...props}` to all child components of `Menu` (e.g. any `Submenu` or `Menu.Item`). For an example of this, see this relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869430/antd-dropdown-menu-error-when-hovering-over-menu-items/68498084#68498084

Answer (score 1):

You need to map your items separately and then push it inside the menu object.
This can happen inside render if you're updating the menu from the props.

```
const menus = Object.entries(scenes).map((key) => {
      return (
        <Menu.Item key={key[0]} icon={<UserOutlined />}>
          {key[1].name}
        </Menu.Item>
      )
    });
const menu = () => {
      return (
        <Menu onClick={handleMenuClick}>
          {menus}
        </Menu>
      )
```

and then render the menu inside the code:

```
<Dropdown overlay={menu}>
   <Button>
     Assign Navigation <DownOutlined />
   </Button>
 </Dropdown>
```