# Antd dropdown menu error when hovering over menu items

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have recently used antd styling packages for my react project. However , im facing with an issue that is similar to the one raised in here [github](https://github.com/react-component/menu/issues/142).

However , im not able to translate the solution they provided to my project. Here's my code:

## NotificationMenu

```
export class NotificationMenu extends Component {
      ###some business logic when mounting component########

    render() {
      const dropdownmenu = (            #<-------- Over here i am initializing a constant for the drop down menu as per antd's recommendation.
        <Menu>
              this.props.notifications.notifications.map(notifications => (<NotificationsListRow key={notifications.id} {...notifications} />
              ))

        </Menu>
      );
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Dropdown overlay={dropdownmenu} onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
                  visible={this.state.visible} placement="bottomRight" trigger={['click']}
                   overlayStyle={{maxHeight:350,overflowY:'scroll'}}>

                <Button icon={<BellFilled/>} shape="circle"/>

             </Dropdown>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
   
export default NotificationMenu;
```

And here is the inner child component that i use to render the 'list' of dropdownmenu items.

## NotificationListRows:

```
const {Text} = Typography
const {Title} = Typography
export default function NotificationsListRow(props) {

    return (
            <Menu.Item className="notifications">
            <a>
                <Title level={4}> {props.object_type} </Title>
                <Text>{props.object_preview}</Text>
                <Text muted>{props.time}</Text>
            </a>
          </Menu.Item>
    )
}
```

However , this cause the rendering to be extremely slow and buggy. Whenever i hover over the dropdown menu item , it gives me this in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: onItemHover is not a function
```

The full trace is here:

```
MenuItem.js:80 Uncaught TypeError: onItemHover is not a function
at MenuItem._this.onMouseEnter (MenuItem.js:80)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:306)
at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:389)
at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:411)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:3278)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3287)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:3257)
at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3304)
at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3514)
at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3558)
at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21871)
at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:795)
at dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:3568)
at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4267)
at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4189)
at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
at dispatchUserBlockingUpdate (react-dom.development.js:4172)
```

Would appreciate anyone's input , thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

**NotificationMenu**

```
return (
            <Dropdown overlay={dropdownmenu} onVisibleChange={this.handleVisibleChange}
              visible={this.state.visible} placement="bottomRight" trigger={['click']}
               overlayStyle={{maxHeight:350,overflowY:'scroll'}}>
            <Button icon={<BellFilled/>} shape="circle"/>
         </Dropdown>
    )
```

IN NotificationMenu Class, You try to delete <React.Fragment>. I've made this mistake before. It seems that using <></> to contain Menu will result in an error.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this happened when I was dynamically generating the menu using data. Because of that, I was looping through data in smaller functions. The solution is to pass props from the root node (`<Menu>`) down to every child of it. So for me, that looked like this:

```
    const MenuItem = (props) => {
        const { item, eventKey } = props;
        if (someBoolean) {
            return <Menu.Item key={eventKey} {...props}>{item.title}</Menu.Item>;
        }
        
        return (
            <SubMenu key={eventKey} title={item.title} {...props}>
                { item.children.map((child) =>
                    <Menu.Item key={child.key}  {...props}>{child.title}</Menu.Item>
                )}
            </SubMenu>
        );
    };
```

Notice the `{...props}` for each element. See also this official thread about the issue: https://github.com/react-component/menu/issues/142#issuecomment-523486281