# How to make a dynamic menu using antd in typescript

Tags: typescript, menu, antd

I'm trying to build a dynamic menu component in antd using typescript.

I have checked this solution in javascript [React Antd dynamic dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59094148/react-antd-dynamic-dropdown-menu).

But when using typescript, it shows that `item` only have attribute `className, key, style`.

So how could i do it in ts?

Here's my code and it failes to build at `icon={item?.icon}` and `{item?.label}`.

```js
import type { MenuProps } from 'antd';

function CustomAppBarMenu() {
    const [ menuItems, setMenuItems ] = useState<MenuProps['items']>([]);

    const main_window_menu_items: MenuProps['items'] = [
        {
            key: 'setting',
            label: 'Setting',
            icon: <IconSetting/>,
        },
        {
            key: 'upgrade',
            label: 'Upgrade',
            icon: <IconUpgrade />,
            disabled: true,
        },
        {
            key: 'help',
            label: 'Help',
            icon: <IconHelp />,
        },
        {
            key: 'about',
            label: 'About',
            icon: <IconAbout />,
        },
    ];

    const edit_menu_items: MenuProps['items'] = [
        {
            key: 'import',
            label: 'Import',
            icon: <IconImport/>,
        },
        {
            key: 'export',
            label: 'Export',
            icon: <IconExport />,
        },
    ];

    const handleMenuClick: MenuProps['onClick'] = ({ key }) => {
        console.log(`Click on item ${key}`);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (appWindow.label === 'main') {
            setMenuItems(main_window_menu_items);
        } else if (appWindow.label === 'edit') {
            setMenuItems(edit_menu_items);
        }
    })

    return (
        <Menu onClick={handleMenuClick}>
            {
                menuItems?.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <Menu.Item key={item?.key} icon={item?.icon}>
                            {item?.label}
                        </Menu.Item>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Menu>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ItemType` is a union type of `MenuItemType | SubMenuType | MenuItemGroupType | MenuDividerType | null`

only 2 types have `icon` property and not all of them have `label` property

```js
# ./node_modules/antd/es/menu/hooks/useItems.d.ts
export type ItemType = MenuItemType | SubMenuType | MenuItemGroupType | MenuDividerType | null;
```

So, you either

1. do type narrowing inside the `map` function (I don't know if it's possible)
2. or use exact menu item types that have `icon` & `label` properties

## Code #2 (exact menu item types)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Menu } from 'antd';

import type { ItemType, MenuItemType, SubMenuType } from "antd/es/menu/hooks/useItems";

const IconSample = () => <span>tada!</span>;

const appWindow = {
  label: 'main'
};

type MyItemType = MenuItemType | SubMenuType;

const mainWindowMenuItems: MyItemType[] = [
  {
    key: 'setting',
    label: 'Setting',
    icon: <IconSample />,
  },
  {
    key: 'upgrade',
    label: 'Upgrade',
    icon: <IconSample />,
    disabled: true,
  },
  {
    key: 'help',
    label: 'Help',
    icon: <IconSample />,
  },
  {
    key: 'about',
    label: 'About',
    icon: <IconSample />,
  }
];

const editMenuItems: MyItemType[] = [
  {
    key: 'import',
    label: 'Import',
    icon: <IconSample />,
  },
  {
    key: 'export',
    label: 'Export',
    icon: <IconSample />,
  },
];

export function CustomAppBarMenu() {
  let menuItems: MyItemType[] = [];

  if (appWindow.label === 'main') {
    menuItems = mainWindowMenuItems;
  } else if (appWindow.label === 'edit') {
    menuItems = editMenuItems;
  }

  return (
    <Menu>
      {
        menuItems?.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Menu.Item key={item?.key} icon={item?.icon}>
              {item?.label}
            </Menu.Item>
          )
        })
      }
    </Menu>
  )
}
```